# Value for mouse left click in SWT

Tags: java, swt

In SWT for right click event they have mentioned `SWT.MenuDetect` as given as below:

```
public static final int MenuDetect = 35;
```

But what is the value for mouse left key in `SWT.class` as I want to add listener for mouse left key operation?

Here i am giving my demo code as below:

```
Form demo1= null;
Form demo2= null;   
demo1 = new TreeViewer( demo2.getBody(), getViewerStyle() ); 
demo1.getTree().addListener( SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent( Event event )
        {

          //code to pop up menu
         }
    } );
```

Now above code is displaying popup menu on right click now i want same popup menu for left click now I tried it with SWT.KeyDown but its not calling to that handleEvent() method.Is there any solution for it?

Assume demo2 has been initialize.
 Is there anyone having solution for it?

Comment: What kind of `Widget` do you want to add this listener to?

Comment: Form is widget.....I just want perform sorting operation based on values of Header on which sorting operation to perform...

Comment: You can listen for `SWT.MouseDown` and then check the [`Event#button`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FEvent.html&anchor=button) field. When using a `Button`, for example, you can listen for `SWT.Selection` instead, but I don't know anything about forms.

Comment: @Baz SWT.MouseDown not working.

Comment: As I said, I don't know forms, but for other people to help you, it would be good to post the actual code you're using (obviously only the relevant parts or ideally an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)).

Comment: Form is not likely to generate any events, it will be one of the controls in the form. So show us relevant code.

Comment: but demo1 is of type treeviewer

Comment: @AvinashJadhav In your question you said you tried `SWT.KeyDown`, what about `SWT.MouseDown` as I suggested earlier?

Comment: @Baz for SWT.KeyDown also not working